# Compare performance of similar models

Tags: machine-learning

Say that I have several restaurants, and have created a regression model for each one, in order to predict how much each one will sell on a given day.

Let's say I train my models frequently and need a way to spot if a certain prediction is too off. The same amount, say 5k might be expected noise for a restaurant that sells 100k daily, but important to one that sells 20k (i.e. I should check the model).

I read about MAPE to try to have a standardize way of measuring the accuracy of these models, but it looks like it is not very recommended. Is there any other performance measure or idea to control the models each time they are generated, ideally without having to go one by one?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> The same amount, say 5k might be expected noise for a restaurant that
>   sells 100k daily, but important to one that sells 20k (i.e. I should
>   check the model).

This sounds to me is a problem that can use ANOVA, the ANOVA can analysis whether the variances will due to the true difference between models or just random noise.

But instead of predicting only one value from each model, you should predict a sample of predictions from each model, aka, use different X's get multiple Y's, as for how many predictions is enough, I would suggest the stat favorite 30. Then you can run an ANOVA between these two samples of results.

Hope this helps.